# Group select boxes into array for post?

Tags: php, javascript, html, arrays

I know how to send data via a multi-select form object and group the data into an array:

```
<select name="my_data[]" multiple="multiple"/>
```

Is it possible to have multiple different select boxes with "single" values and push them all into an array? i.e.

```
<select id="select-1" name="my_data[]"/>
<select id="select-2" name="my_data[]"/>
```

result would be

```
[
    0 => {value of select-1},
    1 => {value of select-2}
]
```

What would be a good way to combine the data from the selects into an array if not possible?

Comment: You've tagged PHP and JavaScript. How do you want to get these values? Server-side or client-side?

Comment: Mark, server-side hopefully so not have to rely on javascript. I figured it out, but the responses are good for seeing serverside and client side options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, just removing multiple seems to work. Zend Framework's FormSelect helper automatically added it when you have "[]" in your form element name and I did not realize that.

Comment: Interesting! And by interesting I mean annoying and stupid. :-)

Answer (score 1):

While you probably can do it I wouldn't recommend it. Just because it isn't that clear from someone else reading the code.

A better approach is simply to combine them serverside. Assuming:

```
<select id="select-1" name="data_1[]"/>
...

<select id="select-2" name="data_2[]"/>
...
```

On the PHP side:

```
$data1 = $_POST['data_1'];
$data2 = $_POST['data_2'];
$combined = array_merge($data1, $data2);
```

Comment: You might wanna change your php to:

$_POST['data_1'];
$_POST['data_2'];

Comment: No clobber. Two `<select>`​s with the same name are no different than two `<input>`​s with the same name: both will be submitted (eg. in a query string it would be `foo=v1&foo=v2`. It's PHP that does the clobber, when you use names without `[]` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This assume you're getting all `<select>`'s on the page:

```
// get all selects
var boxes = document.getElementsByTagName("select"),
    arr = []; // your final values array

// for each select, pull out the value and push it into 'arr'
for(var i = 0, len = boxes.length; i < len, i++) {
  arr.push(boxes[i].value);
}
```